# Do browsers remove whitespace in between text of any html tag

Tags: html, browser, whitespace, trim

Here is a fiddle demonstrating the problem

http://jsfiddle.net/WM8XW/

I have inserted many whitespace in the content of the label tag but the html rendered seems to remove it. Is adding `&nbsp;` only solution to the above problem

**HTML Content**

```
<label>label with very          long white space in between</label>
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The normal behavior for the display of whitespaces is to compress them into a single one, which is then displayed.

There are two exceptions from that:

1. The [`<pre>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre), which keeps the whitespaces as entered.
2. Setting the CSS property [`white-space: pre;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) (respectively `pre-wrap` or `pre-line`)

Answer (score 7):

Browsers usually treat multiple consecutive spaces and/or carriage returns as a single space. In the case of non-breaking spaces `(&nbsp; or &#160;)` browsers will typically honor multiple consecutive occurrences as-is with no collapsing to a single space.

Solution1:

You can hard code the `(&nbsp; or &#160;)` as much as you want.

[Reference](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/indent.htm)

Any text between the opening `<pre>` tag and the closing `</pre>` tag will preserve the formatting of the source document.

Solution2:
You can make use of `<pre>` tag.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre)

If you want to execute with [css](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) also you can perform the same the above answers are only from `html`
point of view

Answer (score 2):

Yes multiple white spaces are converted to one white space by browser. Your only option is to have hard space ie. `&nbsp`;