# Inconsistent line-feed rendering with PHP echo

Tags: php

Consider the following PHP code:

```
<?php
echo "prefix";
echo "
{{ foo }}
"; 
echo "suffix";
```

It renders as:

```
prefix
{{ foo }}
suffix
```

As can be seen here:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4c0b3a3e921b0a761b1cf05f12f709d025d1b2de

Note the line feed between `prefix` and `{{ foo }}`.

Now consider the following code:

```
<?php
echo "
{{ foo }}
"; 
echo "suffix";
```

It renders as:

```
{{ foo }}
suffix
```

As can be seen here:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/18b07b9d05b79703617364b4d301d6799654a086

Why was the first line feed not rendered in the second case while it was in the first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be because the *web browser* (or website running the PHP for you) is removing the extra whitespace from the rendered HTML output.  (See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17784740)

If you run your code on the PHP command line, then you will see the leading newline that you desire.

If this code is going to be used in a HTML page, then use `<br/>` tags to make new lines.

Comment: Yes, I definitely see the line feed when the code is run on the command line. That adds to the confusion. :D