# preg_replace('/[\\s]/','&nbsp;' $mysqlData) causing the text overflow from div

Tags: php, html, css

I want to show data on my webpage as the user entered. so when I use

```
preg_replace('/[\\s]/','&nbsp;' $mysqlData);
```

it shows like this 
[image]

otherwise it display perfect but without giving proper space as user was submitted.

[image]

I used css property: `overflow-wrap: break-word;` but it cuts the word which does not look proper. if I use `hyphens: auto;` it's result display with many hyphens in the div.

Comment: You're replacing regular spaces with `&nbsp;` (nonbreakable space), which means it doesn't "break" and shows everything as one big line.

Comment: There's almost never any reason in 2018 to use `&nbsp;`. If you use it it means there's a design problem you should fix. Start by removing this replacement and only look at the css.

Comment: If you're trying to format those "TLG-4 TLG-4 ..." line you could try to not replace _every_ space but replace every occurrence of two spaces or so.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784595/do-browsers-remove-whitespace-in-between-text-of-any-html-tag

Comment: <tl;dr> You can use the <pre></pre> tags surrounding the user submit, and the HTML won't remove the white-spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Do browsers remove whitespace in between text of any html tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784595/do-browsers-remove-whitespace-in-between-text-of-any-html-tag)

You can use the `<pre></pre>` tags surrounding the user submit, and the HTML won't remove the white-spaces.

Alternatively you can set in CSS the `white-space: pre-wrap;` for the element, and it will not be overflowing, but will retain the whitespaces.

Replacing spaces will non-breaking spaces will also prevent the elements from wrapping. (It's its primary use btw.)

Comment: white-space: pre-wrap; is a perfect solution for me. Thanks