# HTML string with PHP variables outputs extra spaces

Tags: php, html, formatting

I have the following code, which is a plain HTML text with some PHP variables. Some of these variables include conditionals, and therefore

```
The <?= $name; ?> reaches a maxiumun speed of <?= speed; ?> km/h
    <?php if( $turbo ) { ?>
      , <?= $speed + $turbo; ?> if it has a turbo
    <?php } ?>.
```

This outputs the following:

> The viper reaches a maximum speed of 320 km/h , 360 if it has a turbo .

(quick note, the numbers are totally made up).

My problem is with the extra space between "km/h" and the comma, and between "turbo" and the final colon.

If I put everything in a single line the issue is fixed, but I have other sections of the text with much more complex conditions, and putting them all in one line would make the code unreadable. Is there any other way I can get rid of those spaces?

Comment: I don't think there is much more you can do, than to wrap the whitespace into HTML comments, so that it won't show when the result gets interpreted as HTML - https://3v4l.org/OMPa8 If that doesn't suit your needs, then you might need to find a different way to "template" your content.

Comment: Can you show us a reproducible example? because browsers strip off spaces anyway.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784595/do-browsers-remove-whitespace-in-between-text-of-any-html-tag

Comment: you should move those "much more complex conditions" into the business logic part

Comment: You can format your code like [**this demo** at onlinephp.io](https://onlinephp.io?s=RYy9CsIwFIX3QN7hDoUqihZ1S5q7OnbwBaLekFDSlrQVQXx38zM4nnO-80nsrh1n1aA9QQv1y00UagHVPBE9Y3M-NTEta7iPMV0awRlnqG6WQGKbfwIVBNIPSzNo8PrtVr8OUAyjyVwOCez90UrkzJlNsW7hk4T7P7YrQ6KdAbeA1Umcy3T9ojr8AA%2C%2C&v=8.2.8)

Answer (score 1):

I mean, you could just "prepare" "the turbo-string" sth. like:

```
<? $turbo = $turbo ? ', ' . ($speed + $turbo) . ' if it has a turbo' : ''; ?>

The <?= $name; ?> reaches a maxiumun speed of <?= $speed; ?> km/h<?= $turbo; ?>
```

Comment: Yes, and that's kind of what I ended up doing, but makes readability really complicated when the file doesn't have just a simple sentence like in the example but a couple dozen paragraphs instead.

Comment: yes i agree, but i guess that is the way it is doing it "in that plain php" a more advanced approach is to use a templating engine / working with transliteration/prepared strings with placeholders etc. ..